# Showing a href without needing to input text(Wordpress and html issue)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm on wordpress atm and I'm stuck with a small issue.

To save the people receiving the site some work I hoped i'd be able to make things as easy as possible.

So what I did was add a plugin called "advanced custom fields", and I made a custom field.

What I wanted was to have 1 custom field that'd show a link(as text) in the following way:

```
<a href="<?php the_field('example'); ?>">The issue</a>
```

My issue is that I want the link(example) to show without needing to fill in "The issue", because in the backend(the wordpress cms) it's a lot of trouble for the person to fill in an extra sub field called name with the exact same value.

So my question is, is it possible to show a link without needing to fill in "The Issue" or is there a different html tag for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want your achor element to be then? You can use empty div instead of `The issue`, but you most likely want to have some visible element to work as the button.

Comment: Yea but the href needs to show the url value as visible link without needing to fill this in, the reason of this is because there will be 300 pages with different urls on them with in the backend only the href+value.

Comment: Wait I don't understand. The field in between `<a></a>` is the "visible" part of the link. If you don't fill it, there is nothing to attach the link to. If you want to simply have "something generic to work as link if I do not know what to put in the "The issue" box", I suggest you use word "LINK", and swap it if needed.

Comment: I know that's not possible, but whenever I enter the <?php the_field('example'); ?> between that it'll simply do this for example: "www.mywordpresssite.com/www.example.com". So it kind of collides, which brings me to this issue. As for <link> doesn't that work exactly the same? <link href="<?php the_field('example');?>"> because it doesn't show it or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the field "The Issue" is empty and only in this case reprint in this place the "example" field.

```
if (!empty(the_field('The issue'))) {
    <a href="<?php the_field('example'); ?>"><?php the_field('The issue'); ?></a>
} else {
    <a href="<?php the_field('example'); ?>"><?php the_field('example'); ?></a>
}
```

If you need to ensure that a link input from the user is external (that always begins with http://) you can do something like this (of course, before printing the $link variable in the href):

```
if (strpos($x, "http://") == 0) {
    $link = $x;
} else {
    $link = "http://" . $x;
}
```

`strpos` search the position of the first occurrence of a substring on your string ($x, for example). So if the position is 0 means that the string begins with "http://", so it is external, but if this is not the case you have to add it at the beggining of the string.

One have to note that user inputs are tricky (imagine that the user writes " http: //..." with a space before the url) so it is possible that one needs more validation than this, but I think that the idea is clear.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (!empty(the_field('The issue'))) {`? This would take in to account that the field may exist, but has no value.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand you. In a link <a href="X">Y</a>. X is the route of the link and Y the text shown on screen. If you want Y exactly the same than X then you can just print X in the place of Y, and of course, no need to ask the user for an Y value.

Comment: @DavidGard, you're right because if the field doesn't exist... why a condition?

Comment: But as I stated above @DavidGard what happens with wordpress is that it'll change the url of Y into www.yoursite.com/X(www.example.com) and that's not right because then you'll get a 404 error and not be redirected to an external site at all. I know you're right in normal php but not in wordpress and that's my issue.

Comment: Ok, so what is the value of `the_field('example')`? If someone is just entering, for example, `test_page` then the `href` constructed would be `http://www.mysite.com/test_page`. If that is the case, so my answer below.

Comment: Make sure than the url is `http://www.example.com` and not just `www.example.com`. If this last is the case, not only wordpress, html itself will think that your url is an internal link, not an external one.

Comment: I've deleted my answer, as I believe @davidgnin in correct with his thoughts about interanl links.

Comment: And I've edited my answer to add a possible way to ensure that the link provided by the user is external.